# AJAX Response Returns Undefined from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to ajax and jquery,so be gentle. I was putting a simple exercise together and came across some strange behavior. When I try to display the response in the console, I get an undefined. Is there something I'm missing here. I thought the $.ajax method was pretty straightforward. Also, I've made sure that the JSON valid.

On a side note, if anyone has any recommended resources for learning more about AJAX in regards to the JQuery framework please share.

JSON:

```
"employees": [
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    }
]
```

SCRIPT:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f6b6',
    success: function(employees){
        $.each(employees, function(i, employee){
            console.log(employee.firstName);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not a valid JSON , missing `{` at start and missing `}` at end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `employees.employees` instead of `employees`.

> That you need iterate over the array with property name `employees` so you need to access it by either using `employees.employees` or `employees['employees']`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f6b6',
    success: function(employees){
        $.each(employees.employees, function(i, employee){
        //----------------^-------------
        console.log(employee.firstName);
        });
    }
});
```

For example check the following snippet

```js
var employees = {
  "employees": [{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
  }]
};

$.each(employees.employees, function(i, employee) {
  //----------------^-------------
  console.log(employee.firstName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```